# How do I execute some code when new email arrives in Android?

Tags: java, android, email, gmail

How can I execute some code when new email arrives (gmail) in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it work on myself with searching some source codes of different programs. But it is really hacky. If anyone interested, can take a look at [GmailNotifier source code](https://github.com/jonasl/GmailNotifier) at GitHub.

GmailNotifier notifies user when receive new GMail.

P.S: And please note that, it is only for GMAIL. Not all email as title says.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I execute some code when new email arrives (gmail) in Android?

There are no documented broadcast `Intents` that are sent out when Gmail arrives. Gmail is not part of the Android OS, so it is not part of the Android SDK, and it does not have its own SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But, there is some programs which notify me when I get new GMail, do you have any idea how they do that? I'm not asking for code, just the idea I am asking for. I can get unread email count of any account now, so I just want to run some code when it increases, should I check that for example every 2 minutes or what?

Comment: P.S: Though it would cause battery drain (I mean, check every 2 minutes as a service). No?

Comment: @EvanBlack: "But, there is some programs which notify me when I get new GMail, do you have any idea how they do that?" -- care to name any?

Comment: For example Flow (formerly F+) uses my GMail, to notify me about my Facebook notifications (it is like facebook push notification, but uses GMail's push -I receive my FB notificaions to my GMail account-). When I receive mail from Facebook, it pops up and notifies me. Actually I am trying to do similar application for my own web-site.

Comment: Is that a hole? I didn't know. Well, there is many applications like that. One more example, "GMail Label Notifier". It notifies when I receive an email with specified label. Are you sure that it is a hole? If so, I am going to search something else.

Comment: @EvanBlack: Looks like they are using undocumented/unsupported interfaces that they are not supposed to be using. Eventually, those will be closed or changed.

Comment: [Here](http://code.google.com/p/minemessagevibrator/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fmine) is a source-code of a program, notifies you when you receive gmail. I think it can be useful.

Comment: @EvanBlack: Please read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use Broadcast Receivers.

Comment: Gmail does not broadcast any intent on incoming e-mail.