# Sending a message whenever a mail received

Tags: android

I have to make an application in android which can send a message on user mobile number whenever a new mail arrived. Is it possible? If yes then how can i do that.Please help.

Comment: Haha! Thats great! Ok just give me a second and I will do your homework ;)

Comment: hahaha..i am new to android..please help:)

Comment: That will help you [HELP](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

Comment: I have to do it within 3 days..this website will take months to finish..:(

Comment: Then you are too late planning my friend

Comment: I think so...Thanks bub

Answer (score 1):

I think android has no broadcast receiver to perform some action when new mails are arrived (like, `android.intent.action.CALL` is stimulated by an incoming call). Email is not a part of operating system, so it wont perform any action using broadcast.

Comment: Thnkyou...Can i do it using java mail API. Will it work.

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly needed, but as of my knowledge, Java mail API can send or receive mails using via your own mail server. but, your question seems different. pl be specific what you exactly want.

Comment: I have to make an app which will send a message on the ph. no. whenever a mail will arrive in the mailbox. Like a notification but i have to send the message in the ph. no.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818685/how-to-execute-some-code-when-new-email-arrives-in-android    Checkout this link, this may help you.